# Absolute value notation is ambiguous

Tags: notation, absolute-value

What is the meaning of
$$|a|b|c|\space?$$
It could be
$$\text{abs}(a\cdot\text{abs}(b)\cdot c),$$
or
$$\text{abs}(a)\cdot b\cdot\text{abs}(c),$$
which differs in sign if $b$ is negative. Or, for a more natural example,
$$|x+2|y+3|z|$$
could be either
$$\text{abs}(x+2)\cdot y+3\cdot\text{abs}(z)$$
or
$$\text{abs}(x+2\cdot\text{abs}(y+3)\cdot z).$$
The vertical bar notation is ambiguous; it doesn't tell whether it's a left or right parenthesis. Is there a better, commonly used notation for absolute value, other than $\text{abs}(x)$, or $\sqrt{x^2}$ ?

Comment: Use parentheses to disambiguate $\,\left|a \left(|b|\right) c\right|\,$, or `\big|\,a |b| c\,\big|` for nested $\,\big|\,a |b| c\,\big|\,$.

Comment: I think that to write $\vert a\vert b\vert c\vert$ is to sow intentional confusion, to commit a mathematical solecism.

Comment: What would be the point of the first use, however, given that $\lvert (a\cdot\lvert b\rvert\cdot c)\rvert = \lvert abc\rvert$?

Comment: Nice observation -  I never noticed that.

Comment: @Lubin Or even $\,\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 \,\mid\, |a|\mid |b| \mid |c|\,\}\;$ ;-)

Comment: And, @dxiv, $\frac\Xi\Xi\equiv\vert\!1\!\vert$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to resolve the ambiguity in the vertical bar notation, you add multiplication signs to make it clearer - $|a|\cdot b\cdot|c|$. You may also try to read the expression - $|a|b|c|$ - from left to right, mentally pairing up the bars as they come.

Otherwise, one really can't help it being confusing at first glance. It's a notation that several mathematicians have agreed upon and are using for quite a long time, and is highly unlikely to change now.

Though you can surely define the notation $\text{abs}(x)$ for yourself, and use it in your text (having clearly defined it in the preface of the book!). It will only depend on if other mathematicians also adopt it.

PS: While I have answered your question, I find the example a bit contrived. It's highly unlikely one will even *want* to write such an expression as $|a|b|c|$, as it can easily be rewritten in its much clearer form $b|ac|$, thus eliminating the confusion entirely.

Comment: Additional ideas: use longer bars—$$\bigl|a|b|c\bigr|$$—or parenthesize—$$(|a|)b(|c|)$$